# not able to bundle js

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

So I'm trying to make use of the "simple-peer" library, but on their [Github](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer) it says you need to bundle it using [browserify](http://browserify.org/). So I installed browserify, downloaded the library via npm (which created a folder named node_modules), created a folder named js in the same folder as node_modules is located and a main.js file in it containing the following:

```js
var _ = require('core-util-is');
var _ = require('debug');
var _ = require('get-browser-rtc');
var _ = require('inherits');
var _ = require('isarray');
var _ = require('ms');
var _ = require('process-nextick-args');
var _ = require('randombytes');
var _ = require('readable-stream');
var _ = require('safe-buffer');
var _ = require('simple-peer');
var _ = require('string_decoder');
var _ = require('underscore');
var _ = require('util-deprecate');
```

Now from what I've read online I thought all I had to do was to type:

*browserify js/main.js -o js/bundle.js*

and it should automatically merge all of the code into one bundled file, but everytime I try to run it I just get an empty file called "bundle.js.tmp-browserify-52350507248623401324" and the task never finishes. I've tryed to look up noumerous tutorials but they all say the same and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: Sadly not, maybe I can get the command line to print out what exactly it is doing, but I don't know how :/

Comment: Looks like browserify doesn't have --verbose flag or something like that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `node_modules` folder is for dependencies that you install by `npm`. Your code should be in the parent folder. So let's say you have a folder `myapp`. In there you put your code, e.g. `main.js`. And in that folder you have your subfolder `node_modules` as created by `npm`. Be sure to run

`npm install --save simple-peer`

this will install the package to `node_modules` and add the dependency to `package.json`.

Now if you run `browserify` in your `myapp` folder, it will look for dependencies you have required in your code and build it into your bundle.

Make sure your code includes only the direct dependencies, i.e. it will be enough to require `simple-peer` in your code. All the dependencies from `simple-peer` will be found by `browserify`.

You can try the example I posted as this gist: https://gist.github.com/aldafu/3a053353a71bb518bce8f4c66c868bcb

Comment: exactly the same result.. I'm starting to think maybe my browserify isn't installed correctly, would be weird though, since I used "npm install -g browserify" as stated on the official website..

Comment: you got any other ideas for me? I'm slowly getting closer to the verge of insanity

Comment: I created an example here: https://gist.github.com/aldafu/3a053353a71bb518bce8f4c66c868bcb

Click the download ZIP button, unzip to an empty directory and follow the instructions in readme.md.

Comment: you are my hero man. Thank you a thousand times this was driving me insane! I suppose it was because I didn't define any package.json? But I wasn't told to do so in the tutorials. Strange.. Anyways thx for your help! Do you want to post this as an answer so I can accept it? Just in case someone else runs into this some day

Comment: I changed my original answer and included the link to the gist. Please mark as answered.